# en R, como crear una nueva columna segun valores de otra usando condicionales anidados

Tags: r

En R tengo un data frame ("todos") con una columna de cantidad de horas de guardia que hacen unos doctores, otra columna de Cant de Hs de planta. Cuando no hacen guardia y/o planta aparece "NA" en lugar de la cantidad de Hs.

Lo que quiero hacer es crear otra columna que diga: "guardia y planta" si hacen ambas, "planta" si solo hacen horas de planta y "guardia" si solo hacen horas de guardia.

Probé los siguientes códigos y me tira los siguientes errores. ¿Podrían darme una mano?

```
> todos<-todos%>%mutate(porcentajehs=case_when(!is.na(hsgdiaactiva)
                  &!is.na(hsplanta)~ "guardia y planta"),
                  is.na(hsgdiaactiva)
                  &!is.na(hsplanta)~ "planta",
                  !is.na(hsgdiaactiva)
                  &is.na(hsplanta)~ "guardia")
```

> Error:Problem with `mutate()` input `..2`.
> x Input `..2` must be a vector, not a `formula` object.
> i Input `..2` is `is.na(hsgdiaactiva) & !is.na(hsplanta) ~ "planta"`.

y probé con este otro y me pasa esto

```
  > todos<-todos%>%mutate(porcentajehs=ifelse(!is.na(hsgdiaactiva)&!is.na(hsplanta),
  "guardia y planta",ifelse(!is.na(hsgdiaactiva)&is.na(hsplanta),"guardia",
                            ifelse(is.na(hsgdiaactiva)&is.na(hsplanta),"planta"))))
```

> Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `porcentajehs`.
> x el argumento "no" está ausente, sin valor por omisión
> i Input `porcentajehs` is `ifelse(...)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sin los datos no es posible reproducir exactamente el error. De todos modos creo que en el `case_when()` el problema es el paréntesis al final de la línea `&!is.na(hsplanta)~ "guardia y planta"),`. Si no conté mal los paréntesis ese está cerrando el `case_when` y lo que sigue no se evalúa o se evalúa de manera incompleta. Quizás por eso `mutate()` produzca ese error, fuera del contexto de `case_when` el símbolo `~` define una fórmula.

Te paso un ejemplo de un código más o menos similar, con datos simulados, que funciona:

```
library(tidyverse)

tibble(a = c(NA, NA, NA, NA), 
       b = c(1, 2, NA, NA)) -> todos

todos %>%
  mutate(foo = case_when(
      is.na(a) & is.na(b) ~ "los dos son NA", 
      is.na(a) & !is.na(b) ~ "solo a es NA") # aquí se cierra el case_when, no es necesario usar paréntesis para separar las expresiones condicionales, solo la coma
      ) #cierra el mutate
```

Con funciones anidadas es buena práctica formatear el código a lo largo, más que a lo ancho. De ese modo es más fácil llevar la cuenta de los paréntesis.

Si el problema es otro quizás sea necesario un ejemplo de tus datos para poder diagnosticarlo mejor.

Comment: muchismas gracias @mpaladino